# Setting up shopping cart price rule on product (with options) for a customer group?

Tags: cart, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping

I have a customer group who has been promised a special price on two sizes exercise balls. Currently the product is set up as a drop-down according to size.

For example, the 55 cm ball is $15.95, but the promised price is $13.97.
Likewise in the drop-down, the 65 cm ball is $20.15 and promised price is $17.79.

Can you use a shopping cart rule to discount the price, or do I have to break apart the listing into individual SKUS in order to achieve the promised price?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should certainly be possible. I may need a little more information though.

What type of product is this? I am assuming it is a configurable product?

If so, in the backend, each product (size) should have it's own SKU to begin with.

In the case that the discount is not uniform (e.g. not 14% off original price), you need 2 rules.

You can create each shopping cart rule that applies only to a specific customer group (Under Rule Information).

Then the first rule's action needs to be either percent of product price or fixed amount (or whatever you want it to do). Finally, you just only apply it to each SKU in the part titled:

"Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions"

If SKU is not available you need to enable it [info here](http://www.ifuelinteractive.com/fix-magento-cart-price-rule-conditions-not-displaying-attributes/)

Let me know if this helps